# Angular 404 page on Wordpress subfolder apache

Tags: angular, wordpress, .htaccess

Consider my main website is an angular application at `https://example.com`, and I put the content of `dist` folder in `public_html`. Also, there is a WordPress website at `https://example.com/mag/`. I am using a `cpanel` hosting and I only have access to `.htaccess` to set the redirections.

I need to redirect all the angular routes except `mag/` to `index.html`. But, when I use a link to go to `https://example.com/mag/` from my main angular application, instead of opening the WordPress site it redirects back to the angular application.

My current `.htaccess` which is still not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mag/
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html

</IfModule>
```

Comment: WordPress presumably already has its own `.htaccess` file at `/mag/.htaccess`? In which case, you shouldn't even need to make an exception for the `/mag` subdirectory. Does the WordPress site work without the Angular site in the root? Is WordPress configured correctly for the `/mag` subdirectory? Is Angular messing with the link? If you make the same request directly in the browser does it work? _Aside:_ You are missing the `R` and `L` flags from the HTTP to HTTPS rule (the `L` flag is important here, otherwise it will expose the front-controller).

Comment: Yes, WordPress has its own `.htaccess` but the webpage couldn't even reach it. WordPress site worked on its own when you type it in the browser. It didn't work when you click on its link from the main website. Angular routing somehow couldn't find `/mag` because it wasn't part of the angular application and it would go to the angular 404 page. As you can see in the answers, I fixed the problem with an exception for the `/mag`. So, when the route goes to `/mag`, it won't be redirected to `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding an exception for `/mag` like this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mag/`. The whole `.htaccess` should be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mag/ # -- <== here 
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html

</IfModule>
```

**Why does this change solve the problem?**

When you try to navigate to `https://example.com/mag` from the main website, Angular routing somehow cannot find `/mag` because it is not part of the angular application and it goes to the angular `404` page. So this exception solves the problem just because when the route goes to `/mag`, it won't be redirected to `index.html` (Angular).